# Is true that you can regard a cosimplicial object as a simplicial object in the opposite category?

Tags: category-theory

My question is: if nerve of an opposite category is a simplicial set, for a cosimplicial object (or set) can we still have a nerve or we have another definition/object name?

I read from [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosimplicial+object)

> Where a simplicial object is a functor $\Delta^{op} \to \mathcal{C}$ out of the opposite category of the simplex category, a cosimplicial object is a functor $\Delta \to \mathcal{C}$ out of the simplex category itself.

Can you explain better why cosimplicial object *out of the simplex category itself* ? 
Why a **simplex** category? This is not clear for me.

Comment: This just definitions of words. A simplicial object is a functor $\mathbf{\Delta}^\textrm{op} \to \mathcal{C}$, a cosimplicial object is a functor $\mathbf{\Delta} \to \mathcal{C}$. Nerves of categories or whatever are irrelevant.

Comment: @ZhenLin ok, but I read that simplicial set are used for geometric realization. Why is not used cosimplicial object ?

Comment: Geometric realisation is a specific construction of simplicial sets. Some people use "geometric realisation" to refer to a more general construction applicable to simplicial objects. In that situation the dual construction is applicable to cosimplicial objects. Again, this is just definitions of words.